# Is there an advantage to single-ended LED replacement bulbs for fluorescent fixtures?

Tags: wiring, led

I installed 100 dual-ended LED 4-foot replacements last year and noticed that my [AMZN supplier (Sunco)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CRB8ITO) has replaced the product with a single-ended version.  Naturally, I do not want to rewire the 100 units a second time and would like to continue with the dual-ended LEDs to maintain consistency (KISS principle).

## QUESTIONS

1. Is there advantage to using a single-ended bulb?
2. Is there cause to believe that single-ended bulbs will phase out dual-ended?

I ask these questions because if there is a significant advantage to single-ended designs, then maybe I should stock up on whatever dual-ended supplies exist if they are to become extinct.

If the winds are blowing in the direction of single-ended devices, then it may make sense to give up on consistency and replace existing fluorescent devices with single-ended LEDs.

Comment: Do you expect your LEDs to expire in any significant timeframe?

Comment: Good question.  I'd like to think that they will last 10+ years in a storage facility, however, with the Florida heat its a crapshoot/

Comment: I speculate that the single-ended version is both simpler (less expensive) to manufacture and simpler to retrofit. Your hunch is probably right, and whether you should stock up is subjective. I'd probably forget about it and rewire (which I assume is fairly easy) when and if you need to replace them.

Comment: Single-Ended may be cheaper to manufacture, however, they require non shunted 'tombstones': if the fixture's tombstone is shunted, then a tombstone change is additional labor and cost.

Comment: You can't just snip the shunt?

Comment: I will speculate you can but, not worth the trouble.  You would need to remove it from the fixture to snip it  and you might as well replace the it with a nonshunted.  Good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6xe54orVNY

Comment: @isherwood not on many tombstones, no.

Comment: The shunted ones I have the shiny is internal for the single ended retrofit the tombstones need to be replaced. On some earlier retrofits that were double ended shunted tombstones were ok but not on the lamps I use today

Answer (score 4):

I have purchased hundreds of led tubes. I currently use a T8 that is ballast bypass single or double ended and ballast compatible, I love these lights and just ordered 4 more cases. With my T5 lights I cannot find the same specs yet but I prefer double ended because most of my T5 lamps are 277v and I don't like my 277v 20 amp circuits having the pins that close together because I lose at least 2 fixtures a year when chunks of wood hit the fixtures. In the past, the ballast controlled the max current but with direct wire lamps that are single ended a good hit would, and has in 1 case, burn a large hole in a very expensive fixture because no matter how good the fixture is the tombstones are all cheap so when the $1.20 tall tombstone broke on a single ended retrofit it burned a huge hole in the $380 fixture.

So I go with double ended when possible.

Comment: Good fire-safety insight.   I am now inclined to stay the course with double-ended.  I have low tolerance for fire-risk.  Post a link to your preferred T8?